# Tryiing to build bitcoind on mac using port

Tags: bitcoin

I am following the instructions for the MacOS X port version to build bitcoind, but make finally cannot find a makefile to continiue the build:

```
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ ./autogen.sh 
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I src/m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /opt/local/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /opt/local/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:730: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
configure.ac:730: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
configure.ac:730: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
configure.ac:730: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
configure.ac:730: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ ls
COPYING     Makefile.in autogen.sh  configure   doc     share
INSTALL     README.md   autom4te.cache  configure.ac    pkg.m4      src
Makefile.am aclocal.m4  config.log  contrib     qa
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... src/build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for ranlib... /usr/bin/ranlib
checking for strip... /usr/bin/strip
checking for gcov... /usr/bin/gcov
checking for lcov... no
checking for java... /usr/bin/java
checking for genhtml... no
checking for git... /usr/bin/git
checking for moc-qt4... no
checking for moc4... no
checking for moc... no
configure: WARNING: MOC not found; bitcoin-qt frontend will not be built
checking for ccache... no
checking for lupdate-qt4... no
checking for lupdate4... no
checking for lupdate... no
checking for xgettext... /opt/local/bin/xgettext
checking for hexdump... /usr/bin/hexdump
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for port... port
checking for brew... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... -D_THREAD_SAFE
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,--large-address-aware... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wstack-protector... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fPIE... yes
checking whether C++ preprocessor accepts -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2... yes
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,--dynamicbase... no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,--nxcompat... no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,-z,relro... no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,-z,now... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fno-stack-protector... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fstack-protector-all... yes
checking whether the linker accepts -pie... yes
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,-dead_strip... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for MSG_NOSIGNAL... no
checking for Berkeley DB C++ headers... /opt/local/include/db48/
checking for main in -ldb_cxx-4.8... yes
checking for main in -lminiupnpc... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.20.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Program_Options library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_program_options-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
configure: error: pkg-config not found.
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ ls
COPYING     Makefile.in autogen.sh  configure   doc     share
INSTALL     README.md   autom4te.cache  configure.ac    pkg.m4      src
Makefile.am aclocal.m4  config.log  contrib     qa
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ ci Makefile.in 
Makefile.in,v  > :q^[^X^X^C
RCS: Interrupt
RCS: Cleaning up.
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ 
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ 
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ vi Makefile.in 
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ make Makefile.in 
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile.in'.
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$ make Makefile.am
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile.am'.
ginger:bitcoin sven.haiges$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You have to install pkg-config before running ./configure

```
sudo port install pkgconfig
```